# How to check if Node app is running in production or development

Tags: node.js, deployment, production

I'm deploying my Node-Angular app and I've managed to do that. The production check in Angular is fairly easy as the framework has its enviroments folder. For Node, that's not an option.

As I have my dev-mode running in port 3000, **I thought that a way of checking if the system is running in development mode was checking the port**.

However, I'm not sure if the system is able to use such port in production. Would that be a good solution?

Comment: The standard way is to look at NODE_ENV, -> `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';`